# Regex to find a key in a string w Rails Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

given the following string examples:

```
human_id_2, human_id_44, human_id_3123121, human_id_11111
```

I'm trying to loop through and extract just the ID/integer.

```
params.each do |key, value|
   if (key.to_s[/human_id_.*/])
     theId= key.to_s[/human_id_.*/]
     ....
   end
end
```

I'm expecting `theId` to loop through an be 2, 44, etc...

Any idea why `theId` is not being set properly?

Comment: Are they always `human underscore id underscore number`?

Comment: `str = "human_id_2, human_id_44, human_id_3123121, human_id_11111"; str.scan(/\d+/) #=> ["2", "44", "3123121", "11111"] `

Comment: try this /(?<=human_id_)\d+/

Comment: yes they are always human_id_XXXXXXXXX where only XXXXXXXXX is variable

Comment: For ruby regex you can always check out http://rubular.com/. I find it very helpful in ensuring that the regex is valid for the inputs you are using.

Comment: @king `key.to_s[/(?<=human_id_)\d+/]` is not returning anything

Comment: [my test is right](http://rubular.com/r/tBYKMInH2s)

Comment: Why the mad rush to select an answer? Doing so may discourage other answers and, imo, is a discourtesy to those still preparing answers. (Not me.) The point is that there is no rush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just replace `"human_id_"` with `""`? No need to do regexp for that:

```
theId = key.gsub("human_id_", "")
```

Comment: You should also consider using _snake case_ when naming variables, that follows Ruby conventions (e.g. `the_id` instead of `theId`).

Comment: This returns a single string. You need another step to extract the numerical information, but it's just as easy to do both in a single operation, using `scan`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, it does. As what i understood from the question, each `params` `key` contains a `human_id_*` and the numerical information from it will be used individually; so no need to get an array. If this is indeed the case, it think its easier to just use `gsub`.

Answer (score 2):

This will work and filter out if there's a mixture:

```
string = "human_id_2, blahblah blah_other_stuff234234, human_id_44, what_up_4545, human_id_3123121, human_id_11111, sdjfhksfh$##$4343894"
string.scan(/(?<=human_id_).*?(?!\d)/)

=> ["2", "44", "3123121", "11111"]
```

Notice how it ignores the unneeded data.

Answer (score 1):

```
"human_id_2, human_id_44, human_id_3123121, human_id_11111".scan(/\d+/)
# => ["2", "44", "3123121", "11111"]
```